# Adding zero padding to decimal values

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c++

I want to add zero before the float number like this:

```
010.0
```

The code I'm using is this:

```
if(value < 10){
  lcd.print(F("0"));
}

lcd.print(value);
```

But when the value is exactly 10, it adds the zero anyway:

```
0010.0
```

I tried something like this but haven't had any luck:

```
if(value < 10 && value != 10){
  lcd.print(F("0"));
}
```

- How can I solve this issue?

**- EDIT:**

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3B, 16, 2);

#define turnOff 3
#define turnOn 2
#define gateStatus 8
#define btn 4

float ADC0, current, ADC1, voltage, ADC2, temp, watt;
int8_t state, btnState, btnPushed, btnToggle, lcdClear;
uint32_t deBounce = 0;

void setup() {
  analogReference(EXTERNAL);
  pinMode(turnOff, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(turnOn, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(gateStatus, INPUT);
  pinMode(btn, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  lcd.begin();
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  state = digitalRead(gateStatus);
  btnState = digitalRead(btn);

  if (!btnState) {
    if (millis() - deBounce > 200) {
      btnPushed = 1;
      deBounce = millis();
    }
  }
  if (btnPushed && btnState) {
    btnToggle = 1;
  }
  if (btnToggle && state) {
    digitalWrite(turnOn, HIGH);
    delay(5);
    digitalWrite(turnOn, LOW);
    btnToggle = 0;
    btnPushed = 0;
  }
  if (btnToggle && !state) {
    digitalWrite(turnOff, HIGH);
    delay(5);
    digitalWrite(turnOff, LOW);
    btnToggle = 0;
    btnPushed = 0;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
    ADC0 += analogRead(A0);
  }
  ADC0 /= 500;
  current = ADC0 * (2.5 / 1023.0);
  current = current / 0.211;


  for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
    ADC1 += analogRead(A1);
  }
  ADC1 /= 500;
  voltage = ADC1 * (2.5 / 1023.0);
  voltage = voltage * 20.2;

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    ADC2 += analogRead(A2);
  }
  ADC2 /= 100;
  temp = ADC2 * (2.5 / 1023.0);
  temp = temp * 100.5;

  watt = voltage * current;

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  if(voltage < 10){
    lcd.print(F("0"));
  }
  lcd.print(voltage);
  lcd.setCursor(5, 0);
  lcd.print(F(" V"));

  lcd.setCursor(9, 0);
  if(temp < 10){
    lcd.print(F("0"));
  }
  lcd.print(temp, 1);
  lcd.print((char)223);
  lcd.print(F(" C"));

  if (state) {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(F("   OUTPUT OFF   "));
    lcdClear = 1;
  }

  else {
    if (lcdClear) {
      lcd.clear();
      lcdClear = 0;
    }
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    if (current < 10) {
      lcd.print(F("0"));
    }
    lcd.print(current);
    lcd.setCursor(5, 1);
    lcd.print(F(" A"));

    lcd.setCursor(9, 1);
    if (watt < 10) {
      lcd.print(F("0"));
    }
    if (watt < 100) {
      lcd.print(F("0"));
    }
    lcd.print(watt, 1);
    lcd.setCursor(14, 1);
    lcd.print(F(" W"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Then something else in your code is wrong. The if statement check for `value` being snaller than 10. If `value` is exactly 10, it will not execute. Please show a minimal compilable example code, that shows your problem. Then we can try to reproduce and solve your problem

Comment: @chrisl the code wasn't too long so I added the whole code to the question.

Comment: I currently cannot try that out myself, but you could try writing `10.0` (which is a float) instead of `10` (which is an int). And have you tried also printing the values directly to the serial monitor for debugging? Or inserting serial prints in the if statements, to check, if they get executed?

Comment: @chrisl I tried that and also `10.000` and `9.999`. still the same! I can't print to serial monitor, it's standalone with no USB interface...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a rounding problem. If the number you want to print lies
within the open interval (9.95, 10), the condition `value < 10` is true,
as the number is strictly less than 10. Obviously, `value != 10` is also
true. Yet, `lcd.print(x, 1)` will round the number to the closest
multiple of 0.1, which in this case is 10.

I see no better solution than handling the rounding yourself. I would
use integers for the comparison, as they avoid all rounding issues:

```cpp
// Print a float to the LCD in 2.1 format (xx.x), left padded with a
// zero if needed. Assume x < 100.
void printPadded(float x)
{
    // Left pad.
    int i = round(x * 10);
    if (i < 100) lcd.write('0');

    // Print the rounded value.
    lcd.print(i * 0.1, 1);
}
```